# How do cut line using C#?

Tags: c#

How do cut the following line?

```
19 02 2000 01:53:36     System    Line    [**12345**] ----> filename.txt
```

I need output to be

```
12345
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = myString.Split(new char[] { '[', ']' } )[1];
```

should do it.

Comment: aside note you don't need `new char[]`, you can use this overload directly: `Split(params char[])`

Comment: Evil regex version: `\d{5}`.

Comment: @Selman22: Where is that overload?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

Comment: @RobertHarvey this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx but technically you are already using it :) instead of letting the compiler to create an array for your argumens you are passing the array directly

Comment: Ah, shit.  MSDN bit me again; the title of the article is a different method signature than the example.  Why do they do that?

Comment: I'm not sure.Maybe the reason is that `params char[]` is just a syntactic sugar for char array :) (this is not completely true though, you can't pass zero argument if the method expects a char array) I also noticed that they are passing char array directly to `params` in their examples, interesting..